# Error response type error in createAsyncThunk from redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

What's the h*ll? Why err is error for typescipt? There is such problem:

> ESLint: Unsafe member access .response on an any
> value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access)

[image]

**here is main part of problem code:**

```
 } catch (err) {
         // Here is problem
          if (!err.response) {
            throw err;
          }
          return rejectWithValue(err);
        }
```

**Here is full code:**

```
export const actionFetchDataUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'data/user',
  async (formVal: TformVal, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const GoogleAuth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      const profileMail = await GoogleAuth.signIn({
        scope: 'profile email',
      });
      const googleEmail = profileMail.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
      if (googleEmail !== formVal.email) {
        throw Error('There is NO email');
      }
      return {
        name: profileMail.getBasicProfile().getName(),
        ava: profileMail.getBasicProfile().getImageUrl(),
      };
    } catch (err) {
     // Here is problem
      if (!err.response) {
        throw err;
      }
      return rejectWithValue(err);
    }
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, everything in a `catch` block is always typed `any` before you do any assertions on it - as literally `any`thing could be `throw`n in any function called from the `try` block. You could `throw 5` in there, you could `throw new Error("foo")` in there, you could `throw new Date()` in there, TypeScript doesn't know.

So, you are accessing `any.response` there - and while that is perfectly valid TypeScript, you have configured your linter in a way that it warns you about it.
If you want to do that access, either disable that lint rule (assuming you gain no value from it anywhere else), or do a type assertion like `(err as Something).response` here.

The whole issue has no correlation to React or Redux though.

Comment: thnx

Could I send err.response some way?
return rejectWithValue(err.response);

Comment: yes, but as I said, you will need to do a type assertion via `as`, a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) or something similar before you can access that property

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I followed the advice from author phry

```
catch (err) {
      const hasErrResponse = (err as { response: { [key: string]: string } }).response;
      if (!hasErrResponse) {
        throw err;
      }
      return rejectWithValue(hasErrResponse);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little more this answer, or supply some documentation about your choice? Thanks